# Algorithm to share array data in smaller array (s) in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array X ( 1,2,3,...700)

I would like to put datas in five arrays in the order, like

X1 ( 1,2...200)
X2 (200...400)
.
.
.X5(...,700)

What the ***fastest*** way to that gys?

Tx

Comment: do you want all the numbers in the range 1.200,200.400 ..etc to be in each array or you want to put selected elements.Please clarify your question little more.

Comment: I want some data in the first array e.g 1 to 98 , in the second array i want the a next range e.g 99 to 200...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xs = array_chunk($x, 200);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: array_chunk is what i need, sorry for gys who didn't understand my question

Answer (score 2):

you can use `array_chunk`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 0):

Because your input array can contain all elements from 1 to 700.So size of your each array should be 200 at max.
In this case you could create the arrays in O(n) time where n is the number of elements in input array.You could jjust check the values of the number and put that element in respective array and its corrct position.

For e.g suppose while traversing the input array i encountered 350 now i know that this would go in II'nd array and it's index would be obtained by subtracting the original number 350 in this case with 201.And so on for all eleemnts i would certain conditions and would store the elements in the various arrays.